# npm install -g json-server is not working on mac, giving error. What should I do

Tags: json, rest-assured, json-server

I am trying to install `npm install -g json-server` on mac OS, but it is showing error. Any recommendation. What I need to change ?

Comment: In my experience (not related to json-server specifically), in order to use some commands in mac, the logged in user needs to be an administrator with password. If it doesn't have a password, it won't work, you need to set a password first.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding 'sudo' at the beginning.

```sh
sudo npm install -g json-server
```

then enter admin password to begin install.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your command is not.
Use "sudo" before code.

Ex: npm install -g json-server
Use: sudo npm install -g json-server

Sudo "forces" installation or in other words, sudo is admin.